# How to do Alignment of face in JavaCV?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, face-recognition, javacv

I am implementing a face recognization API using JavaCV.
Face detection is working file. If a face is straight, recognized also doing well. But when a face is **not aligned center** it is giving less accuracy.

I searched solution for face aligned in java but I got all solutions in python and c++. Will you help me to get **face aligned center in Java**.

Give me some suggestions to improve accuracy to face recognization in javaCV.

Here my code to detect face

```
BufferedImage image = null;
    File f = null;

    IplImage grayImage = null, smallImage = null, temp = null, grabbedImage = null, temp2 = null;
    CvSeq faces = null;
    CvMemStorage storage = null;
    try {
        f = new File("testImage.jpg");
        image = ImageIO.read(f);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Errorss: " + e);
    }

    Graphics2D g2 = image.createGraphics();

    ToIplImage iplConverter = new OpenCVFrameConverter.ToIplImage();
    Java2DFrameConverter java2dConverter = new Java2DFrameConverter();
    IplImage iplImage = iplConverter.convert(java2dConverter.convert(image));

    grabbedImage = iplImage;

    grayImage = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(grabbedImage), 8, 1);

    smallImage = cvCreateImage(cvSize(grabbedImage.width() / 4, grabbedImage.height() / 4), 8, 1);

    storage = CvMemStorage.create();

        cvClearMemStorage(storage);

        temp = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(grabbedImage), grabbedImage.depth(), grabbedImage.nChannels());

        cvCopy(grabbedImage, temp);

        org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_imgproc.cvCvtColor(grabbedImage, grayImage,
                org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_imgproc.CV_BGR2GRAY);

        org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_imgproc.cvResize(grayImage, smallImage,
                org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_imgproc.CV_INTER_AREA);

        faces = org.bytedeco.javacpp.helper.opencv_objdetect.cvHaarDetectObjects(smallImage, classifier, storage,
                1.1, 3, org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_objdetect.CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING);

        System.out.println(faces.total() + " Faces");
```